# Angular2 - npm Start Error on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, express, npm

I am new to angular and I have been trying to learn more about angular2. I have followed the getting started guide to create the angular2-quickstart project. However when I am running the command npm start, the browser start but everything fails after 1 second. Below is the content of my npm error log file:

```
ramesh@ramesh-PC MINGW32 /c/Projects/quickstart (master)
$ node --version
v7.4.0

ramesh@ramesh-PC MINGW32 /c/Projects/quickstart (master)
$ npm --version
4.1.1

$ npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Projects\quickstart
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(13,18): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(13,30): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(17,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(18,5): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(22,15): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(23,5): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(28,20): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(28,35): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(51,16): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(51,28): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(56,16): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules_rr/karma/config.tpl.ts(56,26): error TS1109: Expression expected.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ramesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Projects\quickstart\npm-debug.log
```

Thank you.

Comment: The same issue. Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still I am facing same issue.